# OleDbDataReader object cannot read the file

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, excel

I have developed a functionality, where I import Excel sheet to the table. But when I upload the file and click on the button to import. The code doesn't works and gives me the below mentioned error. I tried with DataAdapter but that was also not working. Please see the error below:-

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine could not find the object
>   '`TableName`'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its
>   name and the path name correctly.

Also, Please see the code for your reference:-

```
 private void ImporttoSQL(string sPath)
{  
    string sSourceConstr1 = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\AgentList.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""", sPath);
    string sSourceConstr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", sPath);
    OleDbConnection sSourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sSourceConstr);
    using (sSourceConnection)
    {
        string sql = string.Format("Select [Merchant_Name],[Store_Name],[Store_Address],[City] FROM [MerchantTempDetail]", "Sheet1$");
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, sSourceConnection);
        sSourceConnection.Open();
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MerchantTempDetail";
                //You can mannualy set the column mapping by the following way.
                //  bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Mini_Category_Id", "Mini_Category_Id");
                //bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("CategoryId", "CategoryId");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Merchant_Name", "Merchant_Name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Store_Name", "Store_Name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Store_Address", "Store_Address");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edited code :-

```
 public static void ExcelToSqlServerBulkCopy()
{
    // Connection String to Excel Workbook
    // Jet4
    string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=AgentList.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
    // Ace Ole db 12
    string excelAceOleDb12ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=AgentList.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";

    // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelAceOleDb12ConnectionString))
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select [Merchant_Name],[Store_Name],[Store_Address],[City] FROM [Sheet1$]", connection);
        // open excel
        connection.Open();
        // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
        using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // SQL Server Connection String
            string sqlConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MerchantTempDetail";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string sPath = Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(sPath);

        ExcelToSqlServerBulkCopy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `SqlBulkCopy` searchs `MerchantTempDetail` in database which connection with `conn` connection. But I don't see the definition of it. I only see `sSourceConnection` as a `OleDbConnection` which connected in your `sPath` path.

Comment: So, you mean to say, I should call (dr) in place of (conn) to work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved by debugging it.

```
 private void ImporttoSQL(string sPath)
{
    string sSourceConstr1 = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=C:\AgentList.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""", sPath);
    string sSourceConstr = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""", sPath);

    //   string sSource = string.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + sPath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", sPath);

    // string sDestConstr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection sSourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(sSourceConstr);
    using (sSourceConnection)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultSQLConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        string sql = "Select [Merchant_Name],[Store_Name],[Store_Address],[City] FROM [Sheet1$]";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sql, sSourceConnection);
        sSourceConnection.Open();
        conn.Open();
        using (OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "MerchantTempDetail";
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Merchant_Name", "Merchant_Name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Store_Name", "Store_Name");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Store_Address", "Store_Address");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("City", "City");
                 bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define *2 connections*, *one for the Excel source*, *another for the sql database* you are bulk copying to. (**This code has been tested**) If you need to copy to an in-memory data table, use this [example on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex21zs8x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
public static void ExcelToSqlServerBulkCopy ()
{
  // Connection String to Excel Workbook
  // Jet4
  string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=AgentList.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";
  // Ace Ole db 12
  string excelAceOleDb12ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=AgentList.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;""";

  // Create Connection to Excel Workbook
  using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(excelAceOleDb12ConnectionString))
  {
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select [Merchant_Name],[Store_Name],[Store_Address],[City] FROM [AgentList$]", connection);
    // open excel
    connection.Open ();        
    // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
    using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader ())
    {
      // SQL Server Connection String
      string sqlConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=StackOverflow;Integrated Security=True";
      // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
      using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy (sqlConnectionString))
      {
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "Q26382169";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer (dr);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Very important details using variable names above:

1. the database you are copying to (StackOverflow) must be created a priori.
2. the destination table (Q26382169) must exist in that database, DDL trivial, same columns as your Excel file.
3. Since you are using **HDR=YES** option, first row of Excel sheet must contain specified column names: Merchant_Name, Store_Name, Store_Address, City (without [])
4. The name of the sheet in the OleDbCommand (AgentList$)

Comment: I added with my changes, but it is giving me error like this:
"The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data."
at line:  connection.Open(); See my updated code in question